# Excluding a provider from JAX-RS

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to use a set of JAX-RS web resources packaged in a 3rd party jar. In that same jar, there is a set of [@Provider](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Provider.html)s which I would like replace with my own.

Is there a way to tell the JAX-RS runtime to skip loading certain classes?

The resources and providers are in the same package.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using maven exclusions. Similar issue I had and resolved with

```
    <!-- For Restful Client -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>resteasy-jaxrs</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

And then you can load your provider classes usig eclipse's classpath

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that the particular provider I would like to exclude is mixed in with some resources in a particular jar. So i need a way to exclude particular files form a jar.

Comment: This is a build time solution that depends on the person building the war to have eclipse. I was hoping for a solution entirely within the JAX-RS framework.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this in JBoss AS 7 by specifying the providers and resources manually in my [Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html) class.  By default, when you do not override the [getClasses()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getClasses()) method, JBoss would automatically scan for every provider and resource.  By overriding this method, JBoss disables automatic scanning and I was able to specify every single provider/resource except the 3rd party one I wanted to exclude.

To ease the pain of having to specify every single resource class, I used a library called [reflections](https://code.google.com/p/reflections/) to dynamically lookup my custom resource classes which I keep all in the same package.  Here's my solution:

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {
  @Override
  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<>();
    addResources(classes, "my.package.containing.resources");
    return classes;
  }

  private void addResources(final Set<Class<?>> classes, final String pkg) {
    classes.addAll(new Reflections(pkg, new SubTypesScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner()).getTypesAnnotatedWith(Path.class));
  }
}
```